# Bubblesort on List - too much time spent on computing

Tags: c++, c++11, bubble-sort, stdlist

I've created a code responsible for doing bubblesort on list. It seems to work but takes a loot of time to execute . I would be glad if someone would tell me what's wrong in it , so I can avoid doing same mistake in the future

Thought that it may be something connected with auto , but rewriting code did nothing.

```
void Sorting::bubblesort(std::list<int>::iterator start, std::list<int>::iterator stop)
{
    int k = 0;
    int temp;
    std::list<int>::iterator j_1 ;
    for (auto i = start; i != stop; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = std::next(start, 1); j != std::prev(stop, k); j++)
        {
            j_1= std::prev(j, 1);
            if (*j_1 > *j)
            {
                temp = *j_1;
                *j_1 = *j;
                *j = temp;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

Tested on 1000 elements - 9,032 s (measured with std::chrono)

Comment: It would be better to put whole program so people could have chance of reproducing relative slowliness.

Comment: `std::prev(stop, k)` has linear complexity. So, unless I'm mistaken in my intuitive analysis, the time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n*n*n)`

Comment: *It seems to work but takes a loot of time to execute* -- Of course it takes a lot of time -- it's a bubble sort.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1000 element is nothing, 9sec is eternity, this is not (only) because bubble sort but because of the way it is implemented

Comment: as @eerorika says you use your time in `std::prev(stop, k)`, around 99% in it in `-O3`, see my answer to have an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
void bubblesort(std::list<int>::iterator start, std::list<int>::iterator stop)
{
    std::list<int>::iterator k = stop;
    int temp;
    std::list<int>::iterator j_1 ;
    for (auto i = start; i != stop; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = std::next(start, 1); j != k; j++)
        {
            j_1= std::prev(j, 1);
            if (*j_1 > *j)
            {
                temp = *j_1;
                *j_1 = *j;
                *j = temp;
            }
        }
        k--;
    }
}
```

to not continuously recompute `std::prev(stop, k)` all the time, you program does almost only that

Of course a *list* is also not the best collection to store *int* and to sort them

---

Full example :

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

void bubblesort(std::list<int>::iterator start, std::list<int>::iterator stop)
{
#ifdef YOU
    int k = 0;
#else
    std::list<int>::iterator k = stop;
#endif
    int temp;
    std::list<int>::iterator j_1 ;
    for (auto i = start; i != stop; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = std::next(start, 1);
#ifdef YOU
             j != std::prev(stop, k);
#else
             j != k;
#endif
             j++)
        {
            j_1= std::prev(j, 1);
            if (*j_1 > *j)
            {
                temp = *j_1;
                *j_1 = *j;
                *j = temp;
            }
        }
#ifdef YOU
        k++;
#else
        k--;
#endif
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::list<int> l;

  for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
    l.push_front(i);

#ifdef DEBUG
  for (auto i : l)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
#endif


  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;  

  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  bubblesort(l.begin(), l.end());
  end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() / 1000.0
    << " sec" << std::endl;

#ifdef DEBUG
  for (auto i : l)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++  b.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0.183 sec
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -DYOU b.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
3.98 sec
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -O3 b.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0.004 sec
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -O3 -DYOU b.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0.413 sec
```

Note also the advantage to compile in O3 ...

Comment: Thanks , but I'm a bit curious now , how in your code exactly work #ifdef in that case and the flags you've added to compilation command?

Comment: the option `-DYOU` defines the preprocessor identifier _YOU_ ( `-DYOU=123` also set it to 123 but I don't need a given value), that allows me to choose to compile your code or mine without having two programs/files. `#ifdef XX` is a shortcut for `#if defined(XX)`, and `#if` works like a _if_ but at compile time rather than at execution time

Answer (score 0):

It's rather an addendum to bruno's answer, it's better to try and tear implementation of sort apart from actual types, e.g.

```
template <class InIt>
void bubblesort(InIt start, InIt stop)
{
    InIt k = stop, j_1;
    for (auto i = start; i != stop; ++i)
    {
        for (auto j = std::next(start, 1); j != k; ++j)
        {
            j_1 = std::prev(j, 1);
            if (*j_1 > *j)
            {
                /*auto temp = *j;
                *j = *j_1;
                *j_1 = temp;*/
                std::swap(*j,*j_1); 
                // - no real performance difference on GCC with -O2.
            }
        }
        --k;
    }
}
```